# Select name, lastname, brand from table where brand is the most voted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this select

```sql
SELECT firstname, lastname, email, brand
FROM (SELECT brand, COUNT(brand) AS choiced 
FROM users 
GROUP BY brand  
ORDER BY `choiced` DESC
LIMIT 1) AS winner
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

> Error #1054 column firstname in field set is unknow.

I have table users, with columns id, firstname, lastname, email and brand
I need to select one (and only one) random user (firstname, lastname, email) from the users that selected the most voted brand.

So if I make:

```
SELECT brand, count(brand) AS choiced 
FROM users 
GROUP BY brand 
ORDER BY choiced DESC LIMIT 1
```

Result is: brand JOE DOE, Choiced 47.

But I don't know how to obteined the random user inside those 47 users.

I hope that I explained myself, English is not my first language.

Comment: Your subquery selects only 2 columns - `brand` and `choiced`, and `firstname` is really absent in this list. You must join your subquery to another copy of source table.

Comment: *I don't know how to obteined the random user inside those 47 users* ?? Where you have taken from that there are 47 users? 47 is the amount of rows for JOE DOE in your table, for all another brands this amount is the same or below.

Comment: For the most chosen brand, select a random user from users who chose that brand... is that what you want?

Comment: thanks @Akina for the edit. I will try to improve my skills

Comment: @Akina yes the other brands are below. And I need a random user to give him a price.

Comment: @Ahmed Yes, that's right

Comment: What if two brands have the same number of votes? do you want to select only one user from both?

Comment: *the other brands are below* No. Not "below" but "not above".

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina MySQL version: 5.7.30

Comment: @Ahmed. The contest is finished. But for future contests, yes is a good idea that if two o more brands have the same amounto of votes, the user must be selected from all of the brands that tied.

Comment: @Akina. I know that I have to use Self Join, but I can't find the solution. I newbie in this toppic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there will be one brand with a maximum number of votes you may try the following:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, brand
  FROM users 
  WHERE brand = (
                 SELECT brand FROM users
                 GROUP BY brand ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
                )
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

If it could be more than one brand that have the max number of votes then you may try the following:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, brand
  FROM users 
  WHERE brand IN (
                 SELECT brand FROM users GROUP BY brand
                 HAVING COUNT(*) = (
                                    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
                                    GROUP BY brand ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
                                   )
                )
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xB8q7l8M).

Comment: Yes! Thanks @Ahmed this is the solution. I will try to do my best in SQL. Thank you all very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, email, brand,choiced 
FROM (SELECT firstname, lastname, email, brand, COUNT(brand) AS choiced 
FROM users 
GROUP BY brand  
ORDER BY COUNT(brand) DESC
LIMIT 1) AS winner
ORDER BY choiced
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @abishag. The problem is that this solution always gives me the same user. If I have 47 users that voted the winner brand, I guess the result of the query should be different sometime, that why I need a random user from the 47 that vote for the winner

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT users.*
  -- subquery 1 - calculate the max rows amount per brand
FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) max_count
       FROM users
       GROUP BY brand
       ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1 ) max_count
  -- subquery 2 - get brands list with the max rows amount
JOIN ( SELECT brand, COUNT(*) max_count
       FROM users
       GROUP BY 1 ) max_count_brand USING (max_count)
  -- join users of the brands above
JOIN users USING (brand)
  -- get one random user
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```